# finding root directory offset from Master Boot Record data on FAT32 file system

Tags: c, filesystems, fat32, fat

I am trying to understand FAT32 file system and presently I have written code in C and am able to read the partition table and Master Boot Record data from a disk image of SDHC card ( created using hex editor).

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTVII.png)

Now I want to find the location of the root directory from the above data so that I can read the directory structure.

can anybody help me out in figuring how to do it ?

Comment: Maybe `clust_num_of_start_of_root_dir` might be worth looking into more?

Comment: And *please*, don't post images (especially as links) to *text*. Copy-paste the text into the body of the question instead. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Great project, see http://wiki.osdev.org/FAT#FAT_32 for reference (it has been thoroughly discussed)

Comment: thanks @IshayPeled for the resource. I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for geometric storage mediums, figure out something equivalent for you need..

```
RootDirSectors = ((BPB_RootEntCnt * 32) + (BPB_BytePerSec -1))/BPB_BytePerSec;
```